# Scroll list view to top on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using the following to scroll a list view to the top...

```
var appointmentGroup = appointmentGroups.First();

appointmentsList.ScrollTo(appointmentGroup.First(), appointmentGroup, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
```

This scrolls such that the first item of the first group is at the top of the screen. Except, I want the group's header to be at the top.

This seems slightly crazy but I can't see anyway to do this.

Looking at the source [code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/9fe5372c1d80ca8fcff0c4fc397d25f91f6b61d3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs)...

```
position = templatedItems.GetGlobalIndexForGroup(group) + results.Item2 + 1;
```

It seems determined to scroll to the item instead of the header.

Comment: Looks like someone solved this by using a custom control and a simple renderer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47102806/8395242

Comment: Precisely what I'm doing now.

Comment: My apologies. I don't see the subclassed control or the custom renderer in your question. If you are using the custom control and renderer as linked to in my first comment, please update your question with that code so that we may get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: There weren't any - I was working on them. I've posted the code in an answer. I merely meant that I'd thought of the same solution.

Comment: Awesome. I misunderstood. When you said you were doing it now, I thought you meant that was already how you had it implemented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrolling to start of Xamarin Forms ListView with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767966/scrolling-to-start-of-xamarin-forms-listview-with-header)

Answer (score 1):

Shared:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Infrastructure.UI.Xamarin
{
    public class ListViewScroll : ListView
    {
        public Action ScrollToTopImplementation;

        public void ScrollToTop() => ScrollToTopImplementation();
    }
}
```

Android:

```
using Android.Content;
using Droid.Customization;
using Infrastructure.UI.Xamarin;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListViewScroll), typeof(ListViewScrollRenderer))]

namespace Droid.Customization
{
    public class ListViewScrollRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        public ListViewScrollRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var list = (ListViewScroll) e.NewElement;

            list.ScrollToTopImplementation = () =>
                Control.SmoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }
}
```

iOS: (In order to have a uniform interface in the calling code.)

```
using Infrastructure.UI.Xamarin;
using iOS.Customization;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListViewScroll), typeof(ListViewScrollRenderer))]

namespace iOS.Customization
{
    public class ListViewScrollRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var list = (ListViewScroll) e.NewElement;

            list.ScrollToTopImplementation = () =>
                Control.ScrollToRow(NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 0), UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, true);
        }
    }
}
```