# Can't scroll ListView to top on iOS?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

On Xamarin Forms 3.3, I can't scroll ListView to top on iOS.

I try: [Scrolling to start of Xamarin Forms ListView with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767966/scrolling-to-start-of-xamarin-forms-listview-with-header) 
But Can't set scroll ListView to top.
This is my code:

At control iOS:

```
public class ExtListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e) => iOS.Control.Logger.InvokeAction(() =>
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (!(e.NewElement is ExtListView extListView) || Control == null)
            return;

        extListView.EventScrollToTop += OnScrollToTop;
    });

    public void OnScrollToTop(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Control.ScrollRectToVisible(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 1, 1), true);
    }

}
```

At class control:

```
public class ExtListView : ListView
{
    public event EventHandler EventScrollToTop;

    /// <summary>
    /// Scroll LisView To Top
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="animate"></param>
    public void ScrollToTop(bool animate = true)
    {
        //bool animate is not used at this stage, it's always animated.
        EventScrollToTop?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

At view .xaml:

```
    <control:ExtListView.Behaviors>
        <common:MethodToDelegateBehavior Delegate="{Binding ScrollToTop}"
                                         DelegateType="{x:Type propertyViewModels:PropertyPageViewModel+ScrollToTopDelegate}"
                                         MethodName="ScrollToTop" />
    </control:ExtListView.Behaviors>
```

At page:

```
    public delegate void ScrollToTopDelegate(bool animate);
    private ScrollToTopDelegate _scrollToTop;
    public ScrollToTopDelegate ScrollToTop
    {
        get => _scrollToTop;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _scrollToTop, value);
    }
```

At method use:

```
ScrollToTop?.Invoke(true);
```

- I use it on Android is work, but iOS is not work.

Comment: I tested your code without using ScrollToTopDelegate and it works well.  The listView scroll to top when I call `ScrollToTop` function. Could you please provide more information to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my idea:

- Use method `ScrollTo` of Class `ListView` ([ScrollTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ListView_ScrollTo_System_Object_Xamarin_Forms_ScrollToPosition_System_Boolean_)).
- Set item focus on `ListView` is first item and `ScrollToPosition` is `ScrollToPosition.Start`

(use `animated = true` if you want to see the scroll happen)

Create a flag: `ScrollToTop = true` use at layout .xaml that handler change Scroll of ListView.

You try it:

```
 var firstItem = ((IEnumerable<object>)extListView.ItemsSource)?.FirstOrDefault();
 if (firstItem != null)
     extListView.ScrollTo(firstItem, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
```

Hope it can help you!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to scroll my ListView classes to a specific position.

```
Control.SetContentOffset(new CGPoint(Control.ContentOffset.X, y), animated);
```

When scrolling, X normally will not change, but **Y** is the value you would like changed. Using that code scrolling to the top would be like this:

```
// You can send true for the animate property whether or not you want to see the scroll happen
Control.SetContentOffset(new CGPoint(Control.ContentOffset.X, 0), true);
```

Comment: iOS somtimes can set to top on ListView. But first display of it can't set to top. @TaylorD